# Why am I getting an "Unrecognised input..." error when I nest classes?

Tags: node.js, class, less, nested

I'm trying to use nested styles on different classes in a LESS stylesheet, but every time I try to compile, I get `ParseError: Unrecognised input in style.less`.

I've searched around, and it seems like what I'm doing should be valid. The strange part is that it was working for me yesterday. I've had lots of weird errors in Node applications lately, but I uninstalled and reinstalled Node, NPM, and all of my packages this morning, and that didn't help anything.

```
.grid {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:3em 0 0 0;
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue';

    .tile {  // The error occurs on this line
        position:relative;
        z-index:1;
        display:inline-block;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:-0.135em;

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

[Here's](http://codepen.io/tlindsay/pen/kHFmA?editors=110) a link to a CodePen with all of my code. CodePen shows the error, too, so it's not something wrong with my installation.

Comment: The error is in `.effect-sadie .caption::before` ruleset with `transform` properties: missing first `translate3d` value before comma. It seems that the compiler cannot understand what goes wrong there so it just points to the root of the ruleset it fails at.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thank you so much! You should post that as an answer. It solved my problem.